# How to auto detect schema from file in GCS and load to BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I'm trying to load a file from GCS to BigQuery whose schema is auto-generated from the file in GCS. I'm using Apache Airflow to do the same, the problem I'm having is that when I use auto-detect schema from file, BigQuery creates schema based on some ~100 initial values.

For example, in my case there is a column say `X`, the values in `X` is mostly of `Integer` type, but there are some values which are of `String` type, so `bq load` will fail with schema mismatch, in such a scenario we need to change the data type to `STRING`.

So what I could do is manually create a new table by generating schema on my own. Or I could set the `max_bad_record` value to some `50`, but that doesn't seem like a good solution. An ideal solution would be like this:

- Try to load the file from GCS to BigQuery, if the table was created successfully in `BQ` without any data mismatch, then I don't need to do anything.
- Otherwise I need to be able to update the schema dynamically and complete the table creation.

Answer (score 1):

As you can not change column type in bq (see this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas))

BigQuery natively supports the following schema modifications:

> BigQuery natively supports the following schema modifications:
>   * Adding columns to a schema definition
>   * Relaxing a column's mode from REQUIRED to NULLABLE
>
> All other schema modifications are unsupported and require manual workarounds

So as a workaround I suggest:

- Use `--max_rows_per_request = 1` in your script
- Use 1 line which is the best suitable for your case with the optimized field type.

This will create the table with the correct schema and 1 line and from there you can load the rest of the data.

Comment: That is a great workaround but regarding the second point, how can I use a line of my choice from the file?

Comment: My advice to take the 1st line and align it same as I did in my answer. P